# Is it possible to prove that $x=\{x\}$ is false in ZF system?

Tags: set-theory

A object is different from the set containing that object seems a basic idea of set theory. That is, for any object $x$, $x≠\{x\}$.

But I don't know how to prove it in ZF system (Zermelo-Fraenkel axiomatic set theory).

If $x≠\{x\}$ could not be proved, is it necessary to add an axiom for $∀x(x≠\{x\})$?

Comment: Take a look at the axiom of foundation (aka the axiom of regularity).

Comment: Please use the search function before asking questions.

Comment: (I am well aware that the questions are slightly different; but the answers fully cover this question as well.)

Comment: Thanks to Steven Stadnicki, x≠{x} can be proved by the axiom of regularity: If x=∅, x has no element, {x} has 1 element, x≠{x} by the axiom of extensibility. If x≠∅, x={x} implies that x has 1 element x, x∩x=x≠∅, this is in contradiction with the axiom of regularity (that is, ∀x≠∅, ∃y∈x(y∩x=∅)), so x≠{x}.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what form you take your axioms in, but for at least the most standard formulation of the [Axiom of Regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) (that is, $\forall x\neq \emptyset$, $\exists y\in x(y\cap x=\emptyset)$), this is trivial: Suppose there were a set $A$ with $A=\{A\}$.  Then no element of $A$ is disjoint from $A$, and thus $A$ violates Regularity.

Comment: What if you let $A = \{ A, \emptyset \}$?  Then $\emptyset$ is disjoint from $A$.  Does the axiom of regularity imply that $y$ is non-empty?

Comment: @user46944: In that case $\{A\}$ (which must exist by the Unordered Pair axiom applied to $A$ and $A$) would still lack an element disjoint from itself, so this situation too is forbidden by Regularity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm confused.  So applying the axiom of pairing to $A$ and $A$, we get that there is a set, call it $B$, such that every element of $B$ is $A$.  So $B = \{ A \}$.  Why does that mean we cannot have $A = \{A , \emptyset \}$?

Comment: @user46944: The axiom of regularity claims that $B$ has an element that is disjoint from $B$. But the only element of $B$ is $A$, which is _not_ disjoint from $B$ -- namely, $A\cap B=\{A\}$ is not empty.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks!

Comment: I think the axiom of regularity can prove that x≠{x}. If x=∅, x has no element, {x} has 1 element, x≠{x} by the axiom of extensibility. If x≠∅, x={x} implies that x has 1 element x, x∩x=x≠∅, this is in contradiction with the axiom of regularity.

Comment: If A={A,∅}, that A has 2 elements. But {A} has 1 element. A≠{A} by the axiom of extensibility.

Answer (score 2):

usually it is assumed as an axiom, the axiom of regularity. Regularity says that $\varepsilon$ is well founded.

Comment: The axiom of regularity is stronger than saying that $\forall x(x\neq\{x\})$ or even $\forall x(x\notin x)$. So it's not quite true that we "assume it as an axiom".